# iTunes Connect submission code signing entitlements error Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

I am having trouble submitting my newest app update with Xcode 8 GM. I updated my iPhone and watchOS app in this update.

When trying to submit I get the following error:

> iTunes Store operation failed. Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your
>   application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that
>   are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'QX3TDZXXXX.AppName'
>   for key 'application-identifier' in
>   'Payload/AppName.app/AppName' is not supported. This value
>   should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.',
>   followed by the bundle identifier.

I set signing to automatic by checking "Automatically manage signing" in Xcode. Everything looks fine to me.

After searching for a solution everywhere I tried to change the Code Signing Identity in Build Settings to iOS Distribution. That also gives me an error right away:

> AppName has conflicting provisioning settings. AppName is
>   automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
>   signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings
>   editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. Code
>   signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

I also:

- cleaned project
- restarted Xcode
- rebooted my Mac
- revoked my distribution certificate

Did someone else have a similar problem and knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasted more than a whole day on this but I finally found the solution!

**Somehow in my Build Settings, the "Product Bundle Identifier" was only my apps name instead of the unique Bundle Identifier (e.g. com.YX.AppName).**

Click on your project, choose your App, press Build Settings and search for "packaging". You should find it there.

Found this by creating a brand new project and comparing every single setting.

In case this is not what is wrong in your project, these are the things I found on this topic before. Maybe one of these things might help you:

- project > Alt + Clean (Cleans the whole Build Folder)
- restarted xcode (that helped many others!)
- revoked all Provisioning Profiles and let Xcode create new ones (Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details > Create next to iOS Distribution)
- checked that all App ID names where right

  - for com.AB.CDE the name has to be "com AB CDE"
- restarted PC
- checked that Xcode and macOS were the newest version

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! in my case I have to Close Xcode 8, Clean Build Folder and then Achieve and Validate, I have 6 Apps in 6 different project, before Xcode 8, what I was doing was to open all projects and then archive all at once, but now I have to archive them one by one, just a big pain in the ass!! and by the way Source Control is not working either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504782/source-control-not-working-in-xcode-8

Comment: I have found the way to reproduce the error in my case, as I said, I have 6 Apps, the only way that the validation and upload works is to open each project one by one and validate and upload each project at the time, lets say if you have open project A you can't validate project B and vice versa, you can archive all at once but, you have to validate and upload each project at the time.

Comment: Thanks.  Cleaning then restarting Xcode solved it for me.

Answer (score 74):

What helped me was:

I unchecked "Automatically manage signing" and then check it on again.
After that Xcode told me it would reset the settings to the default and after that it finally worked.

Comment: It works, thanks! I love those xcode WTF moments while iOS development...

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

1. Create new "Provisioning profile" & import it.
2. Restart XCode
3. Uncheck "Automatically manage signing"
4. In the drop downlist select new provisioning profile.
5. Check "Automatically manage signing".

It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the suggested workarounds here worked. I assumed it had to do something with how the XCode project is configured, so I tracked back and found out I was following this guide [Building multiple versions of a React Native app](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5) and had missed the following step.

> In the project’s info.plist, change the value of Bundle Identifier to
>   $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)$(BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX)

EDIT : Turns out that was not the actual problem. I had to enable Push Notifications in Capabilities since the App ID on the developer console had it turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I restarted my laptop, rebuilt the release build, restarted Xcode, rebuilt the archives. Then it worked.