# Source control not working in Xcode 8

Tags: version-control, xcode8

I have updated Xcode in order to program for iOS 10 and for some reason Source Control has stopped working.

Im using Git connected to visual studio data repo, since at least Xcode 6 with no problem at all.

I have checked the URL, User and Password and everything looks ok, I can use the Git with the console with no problem.

But in Xcode 8 Im not able to do anything related with the Source Control, I can't commit, Add files to track or even see the states besides the files (M, A, ?), but if I change something the Git keeps track of the change but Xcode does not.

As you can see in the pictures everything looks ok.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone is having the same problem??

Does anyone have a clue on what I have to do??

Dos anyone have an idea on what to check or configure in order to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have same problem and can't find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this very same problem, and also verified that everything was setup correctly. I found that Xcode 8.1 GM seed just became available, downloaded and installed it and I am now able to commit my project without problems.