# ERROR ITMS-4241: "App is Removed or Deleted. Apps can't be validated or submitted while they're removed or deleted." at SoftwareAssets

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my iOS app to the app store. but I have an error when trying to upload the binary code from my Xcode

> ERROR ITMS-4241: "App is Removed or Deleted. Apps can't be validated
>   or submitted while they're removed or deleted." at SoftwareAssets

so previously in my app store connect, I delete my app. and then I create a new app in the app store connect using the same bundle ID. but I have an error like that.

what should I do ?

Comment: so you're expecting it to be a new app in app store with the same old bundle identifier. I'm afraid that's not gonna work

Answer (score 1):

the only way I can solve this error is by changing the bundle ID of my app in my xcode project, and also set the bundle id to be the same in app store connect.

after changing the bundle id, you may encounter another error, when archiving and validating the binary before uploading to app store, you can solve this issue by checking this thread: [iTunes Connect submission code signing entitlements error Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453669/itunes-connect-submission-code-signing-entitlements-error-xcode-8/39473509)

hope this helps you